# How can I solve this? Can derivatives be used to solve this?

Tags: calculus

A manufacturer has determined that an employee with d days of production experience will
be able to produce approximately P(d) = 3 + 15( 1 – $e^{–0.2d}$ ) items per day.

(a)Approximately how many items will a beginning employee be able to produce each day?

(b) How many items will an experienced employee be able to produce each day?

Comment: Define "experienced". For a) use $d=0$ if b) means $d \rightarrow \infty$ then $\mathrm{e}^{-\infty} = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a beginning employ means $0$ days of experience, then he can make $P(0)=3+15(1-e^0)=3+15(1-1)=3$ items per day.

Assuming experienced means $d$ goes to infinity, then he will make $\lim_{d \to \infty} P(d)=\lim_{d \to \infty} 3+15(1-e^{-0.2d})=3+15=18$.

The words "beginner" and "experienced" are very ambiguous and should be defined more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Choose your value for $d$. In the case of a beginning employee, evaluate at $d=0$. For an experienced employee, try taking the limit as $d\to\infty$.

If you are unaccustomed to limits, try different large values for $d$ and compare the results.